# tar is not obeying --exclude-vcs

Tags: fedora, tar, version-control

I am trying to create an archive as:

```
tar -Jcvf shadow-2.7.1.tar.xz shadow/ --exclude-vcs
```

and I am expecting no `.git` folder. But

```
vi shadow-2.7.1.tar.xz
```

yeilds

```
...
shadow/.git/
shadow/.git/index
shadow/.git/objects/
shadow/.git/objects/ab/
...
```

Mu system is:

```
which tar
/usr/bin/tar
tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
uname -sr
Linux 4.9.6-200.fc25.x86_64
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The options should come before the files. `tar -Jcvf --exclude-vcs shadow-2.7.1.tar.xz shadow/` should do the job.

Comment: @don_crissti sure. But the point is hopefully clear.

Comment: @Jakuje Have you tested this? With tar 1.27.1, the location of the option doesn't matter. Has this changed in more recent versions?

Comment: @Gilles. No, i didnt test it, since it was more like guess and leaving something to the OP. Though thanks for good answer with deeper analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Your command works up to GNU tar 1.28. But in version 1.29, the command line parsing mechanism changed. Before, the order of options and operands didn't matter. In [recent versions](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/commit/?id=4cf2af45007b5288dae1037baffa681d37c0b1c2), the order does matter: options that determine which files are selected are [position-sensitive](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Position_002dSensitive-Options.html#SEC44) and only apply to operands that follow.

Comment: Just as an example: `tar cfz grass_src_snapshot_2020_06_29.tar.gz --exclude-vcs grass_git_src`